# log4j with oracle gives exception- invalid sql statement

Tags: java, sql, log4j

I try to implement log4j logging in database example from that page, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

I edit my xml like

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
    <param name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:dbname"/>
    <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <param name="user" value="user"/>
    <param name="password" value="pass"/>
    <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO FLOW_PATH_LOGS VALUES('%x',
                         '%d','%C','%p','%m')"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    </layout>
</appender>
```

but it gives sql exception, invalid sql statement. I try to replace statement as select 1 from dual but it gives same exception.

Stack Trace:

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1035)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1224)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1717)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1685)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:275)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:178)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:250)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:146)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:663)
at tr.com.innova.hukuk.ortak.controllers.OrtakController.logFlowPath(OrtakController.java:751)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at com.sun.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:184)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:45)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:39)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:149)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:257)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:89)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:282)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:241)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:219)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at tr.com.innova.common.middleware.web.servlets.ServletToBeanProxy.service(ServletToBeanProxy.java:46)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
at tr.com.innova.ortak.web.filters.ExpiredPasswordCheckFilter.doFilter(ExpiredPasswordCheckFilter.java:48)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at tr.com.innova.ortak.web.filters.FlowSecurityFilter.doFilter(FlowSecurityFilter.java:38)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at tr.com.innova.ortak.web.filters.IDMFilter.doFilter(IDMFilter.java:68)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:99)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at tr.com.innova.ortak.web.filters.ILoggerFilter.doFilter(ILoggerFilter.java:60)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

I'm thankful for any advice.

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is?

Comment: I added the stack trace.

Comment: If the statement doesn't appear in the exception, then use a debugger to inspect which precise statement is executed. I would at least specify the names of the columns in the statements, instead of relying on their default order.

Comment: I tried specifying the columns names but it still throws exception. And I can't debug because it executes at a function in a jar. I can't see the code.

Comment: Log4J is open-source. Download the sources and debug. Or use your oracle client to discover what statement has been sent to the database.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but no solution. the sql statement is insert into FLOW_PATH_LOGS values('',sysdate,'logFlowPath','INFO','Ana Sayfa')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the example. What you have to do is move your insert statement into a ConversionPattern within the Layout.

So you want something like:

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="INSERT INTO FLOW_PATH_LOGS VALUES('%x', %d','%C','%p','%m')"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: I did that and solve my problem months ago, and forget that i ask this question. But thanks for the answer for anyone with same problem.